# Laravel: Search by ID and display row data if it's found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I already have a simple search with table where I filter data through name, last name, social number etc... But, I need something different, I need search field where will search by ID and display other information (name, last name, phone...) if I found it and click on submit.

This is how my search form look:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'search.id', 'method'=>'GET']) !!}
<div class="input-group">
  {!! Form::number('term', Request::get('term'), ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'ID']) !!}
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-search"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-default']) !!}
  </span>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My controller so far:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $ids = DB::table('electoral_list')
        ->where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
        ->where('id', intval($request->get('term')))
        ->first();

    if(is_null($ids))
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Your Message');
    }

    return view('search.index', compact('ids'));
}
```

and here I want to display a name if I found id:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::text('name', $ids->name, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Name']) !!}
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I get error:
(2/2) ErrorException
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: I add code what I have now, with error. Sorry for not having before.

Comment: Too much information. There is a lot of code here that doesn't need to be in your question. Narrow your problem so that we can help you.

Comment: I suppose I can remove everything where I show how I did it with my other search, but then I must change whole question. I thought that this will help you to understand where I'm going with my coding and to further guide me how it's supposed to look like. But, if that is the rule I'll do it.

updated...

Comment: Is id a primery key (unique)?

Comment: Yes. But I intend to add one more search not by ID which is primary key (unique) but something like social number which is also unique but not primary.

Answer (score 1):

I see a syntax error with your blade, just do it like that:

```
{!! Form::text('name', $ids->name, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Name']) !!}
```

I think this is the reason of your Error:

> ErrorException Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Now you can change the code like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $ids = DB::table('electoral_list')
        ->where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
        ->where('id', intval($request->get('term')))
        ->first();

    if(is_null($ids))
    {
        // Do somthing if no result e.g.
        Session::flash('no_id', 'ID does not exist!')
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    return view('search.index', compact('ids'));
}
```

If the column is unique you should not use `like`

Comment: Yes, that remove the error. Now, it's displaying name with id of 1, guess because of function first() and without submitting. I need to display name when I enter some ID.

Comment: Now I get:
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrFail()

Comment: 5.5 version. Updated from 5.4

Comment: Now the error is: (2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Maybe I'm doing something wrong in view or routes?

Comment: Yes because if the there is no record $ids = null and than $ids->name can't work. Don't hand over a object just one variable e.g. $name that you preper in your method

Comment: Now you lost me, I don't understand what I suppose to do?

Comment: What should happen if there is no result?

Comment: I would place a session flash message like this: Session::flash('no_id', 'ID does not exist!'); and return to same page...

Comment: OK than just put this where it should be: " // Do somthing if no result"

Comment: I already did that but still get error: (2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object Are you sure I'm not suppose change something in view?

Comment: I updated first question so you can see how it looks everything now. And, when I add your error message with redirection, it redirect me to page from where I;m going, I can't enter this page.

Comment: I did a aupdate, but we are not here to write you code.. I just give you a hint in the right direction... it was only one example ... I would suggest that you learn the basics first.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will try to experiment further with this and read documentation and hopefully find the answer. Thank you very much.